# Adding a prototype chain 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var Test = function(name) {
    this.member = name;
}

Test.prototype.perform = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

Test.prototype.perform.prototype.dance = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

var actor = new Test('jane');
actor.perform();
actor.perform.dance();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fj6m3/1/

I want to be able to add methods to perform. When I console.log(this) inside of the perform method I can see that the dance method has been added to the prototype chain and perform has access to everything (I can access `this.member`) but when I log out `this` inside of the dance method it just returns an object that looks like this:

```
Object {dance: function}
```

It seems to have lost access to the parent somehow and now I no longer have access to `this.member`.

Why is this? Is it not possible to add methods to a prototype as I have done above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you call it like this -

```
actor.perform.prototype.dance()
```

Consider this line -

```
Test.prototype.perform = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

This signifies that, whenever someone creates an object using `new Test()`, it's prototype (which you cannot access in a uniform way across all browsers, chrome supports a non-standard `__proto__` accessor) will be set to the `prototype` property of `Test`. As a result you can access the `perform` method.

Now this -

```
Test.prototype.perform.prototype.dance = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

tells signifies that, `perform` which has been added to the `prototype` property of `Test`, has itself another property called `prototype`, and this property has another property called `dance`, which contains your desired method.

If you do this -

```
Test.prototype.perform.dance = function () {....}
```

then this signifies that `perform` which is added to the `prototype` property of `Test` has a property called dance, which points to a function. Since the `actor` object's prototype (which is again, only accessible in a non-standard way using `__proto__`) is set to the `prototype` property of `Test`, you will be able to access it in the following way -

```
actor.perform.dance();
```

Hope this clears the air for you.

Comment: I've rephrased the question. The issue is that dance doesn't have access to the parent instance vars

Comment: @MikeRifgin: I have edited my answer too. Please comment back if you still have confusions.

Comment: the dance method does not have access to this.member http://jsfiddle.net/Fj6m3/3/ . Is there any way to code this so that the prototype dance has access to the same context that perform does?

Answer (score 1):

Change `Test.prototype.perform.prototype.dance` to `Test.prototype.perform.dance`

and `actor.perform.dance();` will work

Answer (score 1):

```
actor.perform.dance();
```

When you do this and all the functions are unbound, `this` inside dance will point to `actor.perform`. You want it to point to `actor`. There are two ways to acomplish this:

**Solution 1: call the method with the proper this:**

```
actor.perform.dance.call(actor);
```

Advantage: you can keep the declaration the same.

Disadvantage: you have to do this wherever you call dance.

**Solution 2: bind the method when it is declared:**

```
var Test = function(name) {
    this.member = name;

    this.perform = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };

    this.perform.dance = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }.bind(this); 
}
```

Advantage: you can keep the calling code the same (`actor.perform.dance()`)

Disadvantage: some new functions will be created for each actor (they cannot be shared on the prototype)

**EDIT: Solution 3: delegate functionality**

I'm not going to give code for this because it's more difficult, but the main idea is like this.

You create another class (Performance) which has the necessary methods and a `target` property. Your `Test.prototype.perform()` method returns an instance of a Performance with the target property set to the instance of Test that called it. The dance method of the Performance acts on target, not on this. It's up to you to decide if the Test perform method creates a new instance each time it is called or returns the same instance each time it is called for a particular Test instance.

Advantage: No more functions created for each instance. No need to remember to call dance with the correct this.

Disadvantage: Complexity.